# problem faced while starting up a database in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a database named 'test' in oracle 11g express edition.Now while I am trying to stratup "test" after shutdown of database, by default "XE" is getting started.How I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail than this for assistance with any problem.  Can you please explain - with examples - exactly what it is you have done, are doing, and what it is that you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the SID on Oracle.

At my job I solved this for Linux/UNIX OS, but it's very similar on Windows machines too. Try doing this:

```
SQL> create pfile from spfile;
SQL> shutdown immediate;
[oracle@server ~]$ lsnrctl stop
[oracle@server ~]$ cp ORACLE_HOME/dbs/spfileXE.ora ORACLE_HOME/dbs/spfileTEST.ora
[oracle@server ~]$ orapwd file=/ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwTEST password=YOUDBMSPASSWORD entries=5
```

Then:

```
[oracle@server ~]$ vim ORACLE_HOME/dbs/initTEST.ora
```

Just put this line:

```
SPFILE='spfileTEST.ora'
```

Now you need to replace all XE for TEST where refers to SID or SERVICE_NAMES (you can use any editor you want... emacs, nano, gedit, vim)

```
[oracle@server ~]$ vim ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora
[oracle@server ~]$ vim ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
[oracle@server ~]$ vim ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle_env.sh
```

Do the same, but now with root privileges:

```
[root@server ~]# vim /etc/init.d/oracle-xe
```

(Lines: 46, 309, 311)

Change on ORATAB too:

```
[root@server ~]# vim /etc/oratab
```

Then just tell Oracle the new `SERVICE_NAME`:

```
[oracle@server ~]$ lsnrctl start
SQL> startup;
SQL> alter system set service_names='TEST';
SQL> alter system register;
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup
```

I hope this can be useful to you. On my servers it works fine.